# .NET TextBox hangs when updating

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to prepend a string a read-only, multi-line TextBox using the following code:

```
private void AddText(string text){
  // output is a StringBuilder object
  output.Insert(0, "\r\n");
  output.Insert(0, text);

  this.textBox1.Text = output.ToString();
}
```

The issue is that sometimes the window ends up just hanging there (even when *output* is empty, and *text* is short). I end up having to kill the application to get it running again. Does anybody know how to get around this?

I've tried using a Label instead, however I need it to be scrollable.

Oh, and I'm using .NET 2.0 for compatibility with another app, so I unfortunately can't use any newer features.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I've updated the code to look like this:

```
private delegate void Outputter(string text);

private void Output(string text){
  lock (messageLock){
    string text = text.ToString();
    // output is a StringBuilder instance variable
    output.Insert(0, Environment.NewLine);
    output.Insert(0, text);

    this.textBox1.Text = output.ToString();
  }
}

private void AddText(string text){
  if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired){
    this.textBox1.Invoke(new Outputter(this.Output), new object[] {text});
  }else{
    Output(text);
  }
}
```

When InvokeRequired is false, there is no issue - the textbox is updated just fine. When it is true however, it still hangs.

EDIT2: Alright, I figured out a fix. I have to Show() the window in the constructor, where before I was just calling Show() when the first message came in.

Comment: Have you done any debugging, is it hanging on the assignment line?  If you break in with the debugger does it show you any disassembly or anything that might give you a clue where or wha it's doing?

Comment: You should use [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) instead of plain `\r\n`, but that's not the cause of your problem. Please post the full implementation of `AddText()`, or of its class if `output` is an instance member.

Comment: What is calling AddText?

Comment: I doubt this method is your problem. The problem will lie with what is calling your method. You are not giving up control back to the UI or this is creating an infinite loop when it returns.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code (although you should use the proper newline syntax environment.newline), you have some other issue going on here, if I was to guess it is some threading issue. Please post the rest of the code

Comment: It is a general logging window, it is being called from an anonymous delegate attached to an event. I've checked the event by replacing the call to AddText with just dumping the string to a file, and it only seems to come out once.

Comment: I recommend that you break and post the stack trace (if possible).

Comment: The problem does not occur in the debugger - when I break and step through, everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic sign of a threading problem.  Test textBox1.InvokeRequired in this code.  And delete any assignment to Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls you might have.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be a threading problem, thanks! I put in a lock and all seems well at the moment.

Comment: Hmm, locks don't fix this kind of problem, they just postpone it.  Is InvokeRequired true?

Comment: Ah, you're right, it doesn't always work. I tested it out and InvokeRequired is false when the control is written to.

Answer (score 1):

I am this form to update the text and working fine for me

```
private void AddMessageToTextBox(string line)
        {
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();

            lines.Add(line);
            lines.AddRange(txtResult.Lines);
            txtResult.Lines = lines.ToArray();
            this.txtResult.Refresh();
        }
```